# Use of java.txt files, polymorphism and delimiters

Tags: java, polymorphism

I need to read from a text file in java and pass that information through a polymorphic method. My idea is a CryptoWallet in a .txt file reading as coin, amount and value, where in the text file its represented as Bitcoin 100 1.25.

Ive got the code reading from the file and printing it, as below.

```
public class CryptoCurrencies

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{   
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to your Crypto Wallet"
                        + "\nCurrently, you only own one coin.");
                        
    File CryptoWallet = new File("/Users/curti/OneDrive/Desktop/crypto.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(CryptoWallet);
    
    String fileContent = " ";
    
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        continue;
    }
```

My main issue is actually getting the text file too recognise the numbers as doubles and variables, and assigning them to run through a polymorphic method. I understand the polymorphism side, but if anyone has any ideas for a possible polymorphic method id really appreciate it, having trouble thinking at the moment!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what role polymorphism is supposed to have here.

Assuming that each row represents a record and each record has the same form then we can parse each row in an identical fashion.  That allows you to extract the numeric values using the parse methods in the appropriate Number classes.

For instance...

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine());
  String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
  String name = tokens[0];
  int amount = Integer.parse(tokens[1]);
  double value = Double.parse(tokens[2]);
}
```

*p.s. obligatory comment that you shouldn't represent money in floating point variables.*

Answer (score 0):

Split the current line by space or "\s+" regex, check if the length is 3, then use the double.parse function from the double object on the 2nd and 3rd element in the array.